# Reshaping/stacking 2 columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to Python/Pandas. I have a list of products with sales and units by weeks like so:

```
Product(index)    Desc1    Desc2    Desc3    Week1    Week2    Week3    Week1.1    Week2.1    Week3.1
Product1          Words1   Words1   Words1   $$$      $$$      $$$      ###        ###        ###
Product2          Words2   Words2   Words2   $$$      $$$      $$$      ###        ###        ###
Product3          Words3   Words3   Words3   $$$      $$$      $$$      ###        ###        ###
```

Desired result is:

```
Product(index)    Desc1    Desc2    Desc3    Sales (By Week)    Units (By Week)
Product1          Words1   Words1   Words1   $$$                ###
Product1          Words1   Words1   Words1   $$$                ###
Product1          Words1   Words1   Words1   $$$                ###
.
.
.
ProductN          WordsN   WordsN   WordsN   $$$                ###
ProductN          WordsN   WordsN   WordsN   $$$                ###
ProductN          WordsN   WordsN   WordsN   $$$                ###
```

I tried doing something with multi-index:

```
iterables = [[Desc1, Desc2, Desc3],
            [Week1, Week2, Week3, Week1.1, Week2.1, Week3.1]]

test1 = pd.DataFrame(iterables, names=['Sales', 'Units'])
pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(test1)
```

On a side note, the dates for both sales and units are the same (eg. Aug 1- 5) but when I `read_csv`, it loaded the second column as `.1` because of duplication. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try using [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) + [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat)

```
import pandas as pd

sales = (
    pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Product(index)', 'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'Desc3'],
              value_vars=['Week1', 'Week2', 'Week3'],
              value_name='Sales (By Week)')
)

unit = (
    pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Product(index)', 'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'Desc3'],
              value_vars=['Week1.1', 'Week2.1', 'Week3.1'],
              value_name='Units (By Week)')
)

print(pd.concat([sales, unit[['Units (By Week)']]], axis=1))
```

---

```
  Product(index)   Desc1   Desc2  ... variable Sales (By Week) Units (By Week)
0       Product1  Words1  Words1  ...    Week1             $$$             ###
1       Product2  Words2  Words2  ...    Week1             $$$             ###
2       Product3  Words3  Words3  ...    Week1             $$$             ###
3       Product1  Words1  Words1  ...    Week2             $$$             ###
4       Product2  Words2  Words2  ...    Week2             $$$             ###
5       Product3  Words3  Words3  ...    Week2             $$$             ###
6       Product1  Words1  Words1  ...    Week3             $$$             ###
7       Product2  Words2  Words2  ...    Week3             $$$             ###
8       Product3  Words3  Words3  ...    Week3             $$$             ###
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to read up on the difference between stack and melt... In this example, how does pandas know the ```value_vars``` is the same, even though there is a ```.1``` in the dates?